# React Native - Need to execute cloud function two time for it to work

Tags: firebase, react-native, google-cloud-functions

I have a cloud function:

```
const deleteUser = async () => {
    functions().httpsCallable('deleteUser')().then(response => {
        console.log("Delete User Response -> ", response);
    })
    signOut();
}
```

Function works fine for iOS (built using swift) But for my react native app im using the code above.

But I need to run it 2 times for it to work.

E.g.

- Press delete user button
- User gets signed out (this is right but it
  missed running the delete function)
- I log back in Press delete user
  button again
- Signs me out
- delete function runs (deletes the user) and shows me the following log

> Delete User Response ->  {"data": true}

Not sure why its not working the first time round?

The first time I try to delete the user (when it fails) I see the following in the terminal (these are not logs im printing)

> Error: INTERNAL Error: INTERNAL

Comment: There error indicates that the cloud function crashed, and exited abnormally

Comment: @Gurmukh Singh, firebase console will show you the logs of function execution. What do they say?